# Converting short-list to byte array, but only using last X bits

Tags: java, arrays, bit-manipulation

I have to compress a list of short-values into a byte array, but only the last X bits of the value.

Given this method:

```
byte[] compress(int bitsPerWord, List<Short> input){
 ...
}
```

The BitsPerWorld will never be bigger than the given values in the input field.
Example: 10 bits per word => maximum value 1023

I also may not waste bits, I have to save X bits in the first Y bytes, and then append the next X bits directly to them.

Example:

```
Input(Short) [ 500, 150, 100 ]
Input(Binary):0000000111110100 0000000001101000 0000000001100100
Output (10 bits per short): 0111110100 0001101000 0001100100
Output (As byte array):0111 1101 0000 0110 1000 0001 1001 0000
```

[What the result should look like](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3kCVr.png)

Any way to do this efficiently? BitSet seems not fitting for this task, because i would have to set every single bit explicit.

Thanks

Comment: Sounds like you have a lot of bit operations in your future. I would suggest working with bit masks and shifts to get exactly what you're looking for. I don't think your question has enough detail to provide much more direction.

Comment: Can you give a concrete example of input/output. For example, if your short list is [1200, 15000, -800], then what should the byte array look like?

Comment: I edited it, trying to explain what should happen

Comment: Much better. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Efficient in what way?

In terms of work required, extending BitSet adding a bulk put method and an index is super efficient; little work and thinking required.

The alternative, shifting and masking bits is moderately complicated in terms of programming effort *if* you know your ways with bitwise operations. It may be a major obstacle if you don't.

Considering you already use wrapper types and collections, indicating troughput is not your major concern, extending BitSet is probably all you need.

Comment: A BitSet would be memory efficient, but I would have to iterate X bits in each short value. So if I have 10 bits per short, I would have to call BitSet::set/clear 10 times for each value, and these methods have several checks inside, so it's not cpu efficient. A compromise would be perfekt. Only using bit operations would be both if done correctly.

Comment: @Laubi The very definition of the method signature already sacrifices performance in favor of simplicity. If performance was your utmost priority, why use a wrapper type requiring roughly 8 times as much memory as the actual data is, plus a reference indirection for each word? Yes, a piece of obfuscated bit-twiddling code can produce a byte[] directly in some less CPU cycles. Only the context strongly suggests this will be a wasted effort.

Answer (score 0):

You need to perform some bit manipulations, and for that to work you need to find a repeatable pattern. In this case, you have a list of "short" values, but actually you just use the rightmost 10 bits. Since you want to pack those into bytes, the minimum repeatable pattern is 40 bits long (5 bytes, 4 10-bit values). That is the "block size" for processing.

You would then have a loop that would do the main parsing of full blocks, plus maybe a special case at the end for the final incomplete block.

```
byte[] pack10(List<Short> source) {
    final int nBlk = source.size() / 4;
    final int remBits = (source.size() % 4) * 10;
    final int remBytes = (remBits / 8) + (remBits % 8 > 0 ? 1 : 0);
    byte[] ret = new byte[nBlk*5 + remBytes];

    final short bitPat = (short)0b0000001111111111;
    for (int iBlk = 0; iBlk < nBlk; ++iBlk) {
        // Parse full blocks
        List<Short> curS = source.subList(iBlk*4, (iBlk+1)*4);
        ret[iBlk*5  ] = (byte) ((curS.get(0) & bitPat) >> 2);
        ret[iBlk*5+1] = (byte) ((curS.get(0) & bitPat) << 6
                              | (curS.get(1) & bitPat) >> 4);
        ret[iBlk*5+2] = (byte) ((curS.get(1) & bitPat) << 4
                              | (curS.get(2) & bitPat) >> 6);
        ret[iBlk*5+3] = (byte) ((curS.get(2) & bitPat) << 2
                              | (curS.get(3) & bitPat) >> 8);
        ret[iBlk*5+4] = (byte)  (curS.get(3) & bitPat);
    }
    // Parse final values
    List<Short> remS = source.subList(nBlocks*4, source.size());
    if (remS.size() >= 1) {
        ret[nBlk*5  ] = (byte) ((remS.get(0) & bitPat) >> 2);
        ret[nBlk*5+1] = (byte) ((remS.get(0) & bitPat) << 6);
    } 
    if (remS.size() >= 2) { // The first byte is appended to
        ret[nBlk*5+1] |= (byte) ((remS.get(1) & bitPat) >> 4);
        ret[nBlk*5+2]  = (byte) ((remS.get(1) & bitPat) << 4);
    }
    if (remS.size() == 3) { // The first byte is appended to
        ret[iBlk*5+2] |= (byte) ((curS.get(2) & bitPat) >> 6);
        ret[iBlk*5+3]  = (byte) ((curS.get(2) & bitPat) << 2);
    }
    return ret;
}
```

That is a specific version for 10-bit values; if you want a version with a generic number of values you'd have to generalise from that. The bit pattern operations changes, and all the system becomes less efficient if the pattern is computed at runtime (i.e. if the number of bits is a variable like in your example).

Answer (score 0):

There are several people who have already written a `BitOutputStream` in Java. Pick one of them, wrap it in a `ByteArrayOutputStream`, and you’re done.